# Android emulator does not recognize .php extension for web pages

Tags: php, android, html, android-emulator

I am trying to write a php code for mobile web app. But the problem is when I test that page in android emulator then it says error loading. when I turn it back to .html then it loads that page.

Can someone tell me why and how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is not in the emulator but on the server. Read about content-type http header and mime types.

Comment: look at your web server error logs or to your php log files.

Comment: I am using mongoose-3.0 server. Does it have any problem?

Comment: try adding <? header('Content-Type: text/html',true); ?> as first line of your scripts, but there should be no need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try your page on web browser before the emulator. Seems it's not a emulator issue.